# Wordpress Comments with Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, comments, custom-post-type

Just wanted to know if it's possible to have comment forms inside of a custom post portfolio? Right now what is happening is the portfolios display as supposed to but the comment form for each portfolio is displaying outside of the portfolio. I'm calling the portfolios with a shortcode placed in a page and then querying that page to display the portfolios.
I've tried placing .comments_template(). inside of a div inside of the portfolio but wordpress is ignoring that div and placing it elsewhere. Any ideas?